# Closed form if any for infinite product

Tags: factorial, infinite-product

what is the closed form *if any* of the following

$$ \left(1+\frac{1}{1!}\right)\left(1+\frac{1}{2!}\right)\left(1+\frac{1}{3!}\right)...$$

I thought of this while solving a problem like this-

$$\left(1+\frac{1}{3^{2^0}}\right)\left(1+\frac{1}{3^{2^1}}\right)\left(1+\frac{1}{3^{2^2}}\right)\cdots$$ the answer is $\frac{3}{2}$ using the fact that because every integer can be written in base $2$ this infinite product gives every possible power of $3$.

Comment: You mean [$\prod_{n=1}^\infty (1+1/n!)$](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=product+of+(1%2B1%2Fn!)+for+n+%3D+1+to+infinity) and [$\prod_{n=1}^\infty (1+1/3^n)$](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=product+of+(1%2B1%2F3%5En)+for+n+%3D+1+to+infinity)?

Comment: @Eff  The second product is not that in the question , only the powers of two appear as an exponent.

Comment: @Peter Ah, I didn't notice it skipped a power... Thanks!

Comment: @Peter I guess this is the correct one then: $\prod_{n=1}^\infty (1+1/(3^{2^{n-1}}))$.

Comment: Wolfram alpha tells me it is approximately 3.682, but I can't tell you if that helps for a closed form.

Comment: @Luke If Wolfram Alpha does not find a closed form, this is at least a bad sign.

Comment: @Eff Yes, it is

Comment: @user108128 no, that one has an upper limit and is also not the right factor. This question is about the product with the factorial above and the other double power product with base 3 is only for context.